# How to compare cpp and python outputs?

Tags: python, c++, performance, function, benchmarking

I am trying to reproduce some functionality from Python in C++. It is an involved numerical method with a bunch of subfunctions.

Is there a nice way to compare the values of the Python functions with the C++ functions that I am writing and that should mirror them?

Could someone paste some code or give a mini tutorial?
Or some pointers or references?

Many thanks!
Artabalt

Comment: elaborate with an example for better grasp

Comment: What values? Do you mean something like unit tests? But since you tagged the question with "benchmarking" maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Write the output to two files, and then compare the files.

Comment: I mean for instance numpy.linalg.norm will give a certain output, and i want to make sure that it has close enough value to the norm function that I would write in cpp.
I suppose comparing the files would work, and since it is easier to read / parse files in python, have my cpp unit testing framework write data to some files, and then I could write a python script to run through it. 
Was just wondering if there was not an "easier way" of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Testing.

Write tests for the functionality on Python (unless they already exist; Python code is usually tested).

Port the tests to C++. Then make your C++ functions pass the tests. Ideally, make the tests a target on your makefile and run them whenever you can.

---

Edit:

You **can** test randomly, if it's a good idea or not, might depend on your particular case.
The rule of thumb is to use a couple of each border case (you can use *code coverage* to see if there's a case that you're missing).

As an example, at my work I use an integration test that requires a lot of components. We simulate a betting process (all the process excluding user interface), at a given point in time, with a hardcoded server response, and we simulate the hardware printer with a redirection to a bmp.

Now, you can't test **everything**. I can't test every valid combination of numbers (6 numbers from 0 to 36?), in every possible order. Neither can I test every invalid combination (infinite?). You test a couple. The meaningful ones.

So we give it always the same numbers. The test is that it has to produce always the same bmp (has to render fonts the same, has to have the same texts, the same betting date, etc.).

Now, depending on your code and your application is the level of automation that generating this tests can have.

I don't know your particular case, but I would start creating a little program (the simpler, the better) that uses your library. One implementation in Python, one implementation in C++. If you were testing a string library, for example, you do a small program that deletes a letter inside a string, adds up a text, erases every other letter, etc.

Then you automate for a couple of test cases:

```
cat largetext.txt | ./my_python_program > output.pyhthon_program.txt
cat largetext.txt | ./my_cpp_program > output.cpp_program.txt
diff output.pyhthon_program.txt output.cpp_program.txt || echo "ERROR"
```

The ideal case is that everytime you compile, the tests get run (this can be done if the code is simple; if not, you can do testing at the end of the day, as an example).

This doesn't *grant* the programs are the same (you can't test every possible input). But gives you some confidence. If you see something is not right, **you first add it to your test, then make it fail, then fix it until it passess**.

Regards.

Comment: Dear Mirko, that is certainly an option, but I was thinking of a more "randomized testing", for instance by generating random vectors or matrices (many) and looking whether the output was nearly the same in all instances.

Comment: I was thinking that another idea would be to write a provider module in ZMQ, two zmq modules, one in python the other in cpp, and then another module that eats the outputs and compares them. But your approach is much simpler to implement, the drawback is that one has to define all the test cases in both C++ and Python once more.